# cp -r * except dont copy any .pdf files - copy a directory subtree while excluding files with a given extension

Tags: bash, sh, glob, cp

<sup>Editor's note: In the original form of the question the aspect of copying an entire *subtree* was not readily obvious.</sup>

How do I copy all the files from one directory subtree to another but omit all files of one type?

Does bash handle regex?

Something like: `cp -r !*.pdf /var/www/ .`?

**EDIT 1**

I have a find expression: `find /var/www/ -not -iname "*.pdf"`

This lists all the files that I want to copy. How do I pipe this to a copy command?

**EDIT 2**

This works so long as the argument list is not too long:

```
sudo cp `find /var/www/ -not -iname "*.pdf"` .
```

**EDIT 3**

One issue though is that I am running into issues with losing the directory structure.

Comment: the general answer to questions like this is to use `find` to generate the list of files, then apply whatever command it is (in this case `cp`) to the list.

Comment: man cp  and or man find  will be helpful.    You can also tar across a pipe to get fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash can't help here, unfortunately.

Many people use either `tar` or `rsync` for this type of task because each of them is capable of recursively copying files, and each provides an `--exclude` argument for excluding certain filename patterns.  `tar` is more likely to be installed on a given machine, so I'll show you that.

**Assuming you are currently in the destination directory,** the shell command:

```
tar -cC /var/www . | tar -x
```

will copy all files from `/var/www` into the current directory recursively.

To filter out the PDF files, use:

```
tar -cC /var/www --exclude '*.pdf' . | tar -x
```

Multiple `--exclude` arguments can be given, so:

```
tar -cC /var/www --exclude '*.pdf' --exclude '*.txt' . | tar -x
```

would exclude .txt files as well.

Answer (score 0):

[K. A. Buhr's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40880120/45375) is a concise solution that reflects the intent well and is easily extensible if *multiple* extensions should be excluded.

Trying to **do it with POSIX utilities and POSIX-compliant options alone** requires a slightly different approach:

```
cp -pR /var/www/. . && find . -name '*.pdf' -exec rm {} +
```

In other words: copy the whole subtree first, then remove all `*.pdf` files from the *destination* subtree.

Note:

- `-p` preserves the original files' attributes in terms of file timestamps, ownership, and permission bits (`tar` appears to do that by default); without `-p`,  the copies will be owned by the current user and receive new timestamps (though the permission bits are preserved).
- Using `cp` has one advantage over `tar`: you get more control over how *symlinks* among the source files are handled, via the `-H`, `-L`, and `-P` options - see the [POSIX spec. for `cp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html).

  - `tar` invariably seems to copy symlinks as-is.
- `-R` supersedes the legacy `-r` option for `cp`, as the latter's behavior with non-regular files is ill-defined - see the `RATIONALE` section in the [POSIX spec. for `cp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html)
- Neither `-iname` for case-insensitive matching nor `-delete` are part of the [POSIX spec. for `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), but both GNU `find` and BSD/macOS `find` support them.
- Note how source path `/var/www/.` ends in `/.` to ensure that its *contents* are copied to the destination path (as opposed to putting everything into a `www` subfolder).

  - With *BSD* `cp`, `/var/www/` (trailing `/`) would work too, but *GNU* `cp` treats `/var/www` and `/var/www/` the same.

---

As for **your questions and solution attempts**:

> Does bash handle regex?

In the context of filename expansion (globbing), Bash only understands [patterns](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13), not regexes (Bash does have the `=~` regex-matching operator for string matching inside `[[ ... ]]` conditionals, however).

As a nonstandard extension, Bash implements the `extglob` shell option, which [adds additional constructs to the pattern-matching notation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) to allow for more sophisticated matching, such as `!(...)` for *negating* matchings, which is what you're looking for.

If you combine that with another nonstandard shell option, `globstar` (`**`, Bash v4+), you can construct a single pattern that matches all items *except* a given sub-pattern *across an entire subtree*:

```
/var/www/**/!(*.pdf)
```

does find all non-PDF filesystem items in the subtree of `/var/www/`.

However, combining that pattern with `cp` won't work as intended: with `-R`, any subdirs. are still copied in full; without `-R`, subdirs. are ignored altogether.

*Caveats*:

- By default, patterns (globs) ignore *hidden* items unless explicitly matched (`*` will only match non-hidden items). To include them, set shell option `dotglob` first.
- Matching is case-*sensitive* by default; turn on shell option `nocaseglob` to make it case-insensitive.

---

`find /var/www/ -not -iname "*.pdf"` in essence yields the same as the extended glob above, except with case-insensitive matching, hidden items invariably included, and the output paths (generally) not in the same order.

However, *copying* the output paths to their intended destination is the nontrivial part: you'd have to construct analogous subdirs. in the destination dir. on the fly, and you'd have to do so for each input path separately, which will also be quite slow.

Your own attempt, `` sudo cp `find /var/www/ -not -iname "*.pdf"` . ``, falls short in several respects:

- As you've discovered yourself, this copies all matching items into a *single* destination directory.
- The output of the command substitution, `` `...` ``, is subject to shell expansions, namely word-splitting and filename expansion, which may break the command, notably with filenames with embedded spaces.
- Note: As written, all destination items will be owned by the *root* user.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** As per @mklement0's comment below, these solutions are not suitable for directory tree recursion--they will only work on one directory, as per the OP's original form of the question.

@rorschach.  Yes, you can do this.

**Using `cp`:**

Set your Bash shell's `extglob` option and type:

```
shopt -s extglob #You can set this in your shell startup to enable it by default
cp /var/www/!(*.pdf) .
```

If you wish to turn off (unset) this (or any other) shell option, use:

```
shopt -u extglob #or whatever shell option you wish to unset
```

**Using `find`**

If you prefer using `find`, you can use `xargs` to execute the operation you would like Bash to perform:

```
find /var/www/ ! -iname "*.pdf" -maxdepth 1 | xargs -I{} cp {} .
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that you'd have to use `cp -R /var/www/!(*.pdf) .`, this would only exclude PDF files located _directly_ in `/var/www`, not in any descendent dirs. If you also turn on `globstar` (Bash 4+), glob `/var/www/**/!(*.pdf)` gives you what you want _in principle_, but it won't work as intended with `cp` - neither with nor without `-R`. The `find` solutions falls short, because it copies everything into a _single_ target dir. (again, leaving aside that `/var/www` is the _source_ dir., and leaving aside that `-exec` is the better tool for this approach in general).

Comment: Ah. +1 to your comment.  I had answered the text of the question which asks to copy "all the files from one directory but omit[ting] all files of one type".  But I also see the OP also provides a cp line with -R.

You are quite correct regarding the limitations of extglob, globstar and find.  I had ignored the -r in the cp command since the question explicitly asks about "all the files in one directory".

Also fixed the direction of the copy to match the OP's examples.